# how can I make a google maps marker that in/decreases in size with the map zoom?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a map that I'd like to be similar to this one, http://trafficways.org/#11/42.3725/-443.2043/gps-dots/base/13/0.05917/1.23/0.5/twos/antialias/nogps/nomercator/. The problem is, when I'm zoomed in, the marker icons look great, but when I'm zooming out, the icon markers are huge, and really overtake the map.

Is there a practiced way to have markers grow and shrink as you zoom in and out of a map? This map will likely have a few thousand markers in it once it's done, so I'd want to make sure I can keep things efficient!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MarkerManager](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/reference.html) to change icons at different zoom levels. They're PNG files. You can make them look like whatever you want. They don't really "zoom" - it's just a bitmap.

Comment: that adds/removes markers as they get too clustered, but it doesn't modify the size. if I made a marked that perfectly covered a block on a map, I'd want it to continue to cover only that block as you zoomed in and out.